# TikZ: tikzset to set a macro and pass forward a key-val

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-pic, tikzset

I've made a TikZ pic called gen(erator). I would like to establish a TikZ key that passes rotate=90 to this pic, but also sets a macro called `\complabelanchor` that changes the anchor, so that if I pass `pic text` to the pic, the text is anchored east and appears to the left side as shown in the image below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,babel}

\def\myunitlength{5mm}

\tikzset{
  LeftComp/.style={....} %% I would like LeftComp to pass 'rotate=-90' to the pic, and define \complabelanchor as "east"
}

\gdef\complabelanchor{north}

\tikzset{
gen/.pic = { %
            \node[draw, inner sep=0, circle=0.7*\myunitlength,minimum size=0.7*\myunitlength] (-dum) at (0,-\myunitlength) {};
            \draw(0,0) edge (-dum);
            \coordinate (-b) at (0.0, -1.6*\myunitlength);
            \node [inner sep=0pt,align=left,font=\footnotesize,anchor=\complabelanchor,\tikzpictextoptions] at (-b) {\tikzpictext};
            \gdef\complabelanchor{north}

    }
}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic [pic text=default behavior] at (0,0) {gen};

        %%%% I'm trying to capture this behavior with a single key called LeftComp
        \gdef\complabelanchor{east} %%
        \pic [rotate=-90,
            %%%%
            pic text=left side component] at (0,0) {gen};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a parameter (with `north` as default value) to your pic to get the orientation:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,quotes,babel}
\def\myunitlength{5mm}

\tikzset{
  gen/.pic={
    \node[draw, inner sep=0, circle=0.7*\myunitlength,minimum size=0.7*\myunitlength] (-dum) at (0,-\myunitlength) {};
    \draw(0,0) edge (-dum);
    \coordinate (-b) at (0.0, -1.6*\myunitlength);
    \node [inner sep=0pt,align=left,font=\footnotesize,anchor=#1,\tikzpictextoptions] at (-b) {\tikzpictext};
  },
  pics/gen/.default=north,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic [pic text=default behavior] at (0,0) {gen };
  \pic [rotate=-90, pic text=left side component] at (-3,0) {gen=east};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is a second solution closer to what you were asking for:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,quotes,babel}
\def\myunitlength{5mm}

\tikzset{
  gen orientation/.store in=\gencomplabel,
  gen orientation=north, % default value
  gen/.pic={
    \node[draw, inner sep=0, circle=0.7*\myunitlength,minimum size=0.7*\myunitlength] (-dum) at (0,-\myunitlength) {};
    \draw(0,0) edge (-dum);
    \coordinate (-b) at (0.0, -1.6*\myunitlength);
    \node [inner sep=0pt,align=left,font=\footnotesize,anchor=\gencomplabel,\tikzpictextoptions] at (-b) {\tikzpictext};
  },
  gen rotate/.is choice,
  gen rotate/bottom/.style={rotate=0,gen orientation=north},
  gen rotate/left/.style={rotate=-90,gen orientation=east},
  gen rotate/right/.style={rotate=90,gen orientation=west},
  gen rotate/top/.style={rotate=180,gen orientation=south},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic [gen rotate=bottom, pic text=default (bottom) behavior] at (0,0) {gen};
  \pic [gen rotate=left, pic text=left side component] at (-1,0) {gen};  
  \pic [gen rotate=right, pic text=right side component] at (-4,1) {gen};  
  \pic [gen rotate=top, pic text=top side component] at (0,1) {gen};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever and efficient second solution. I learnt a lot from that. I just wonder why you use `\gencomplabel` here. Wouldn't it be possible to directly set the anchor into the `gen rotate` styles choices, like `gen rotate/bottom/.style={rotate=0,anchor=north}`?

Comment: @SebGlav try that out, but I don't think it would work. Anchor isn't quite the same in a pic vs mode. With the rotated versions, I rotate the pic axes but it's still drawn from the origin, and I only want to change the text anchor

Comment: Your second solution was definitely what I was looking for. Out of curiousity, if we use `gen rotate=left` on one pic, and then omit `gen rotate` on the next, why do we NOT have to reset `\gencomplabel`? Does TikZ build some hook into `\gencomplabel` that checks the default value? Not complaining as this behavior is exactly what I want, but at a surface level I thought we'd need do pre-define `gencomplabel` initially then reset to the desired default (north) after a pic use.

Comment: @likethevegetable A path is a scope, so any modification made to a macro during a path disappears at the end of that path.

Comment: @likethevegetable In fact, `% defaull value` should be `% initial value`...